# Database connection to an OLAP using java

Tags: java, database, ssas, olap

I had searched so much about a script that can help me to connect my OLAP database to my Java project but I can't find any thing useful. Could Some one help me please?
My server name :"DESKTOP-C80O1IJ\LEONI"
My OLAP Database name :"SophosDW"

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition and I have integrated "OLAP4J" as my API.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you seen https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j#writing-a-simple-program?

Comment: Actually Yes I have seen it, Here is the code that I took: 
public class Connexion {

Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:xmla:Server=DESKTOP-C80O1IJ\\LEONI");
OlapConnection olapConnection = connection.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
OlapStatement statement = olapConnection.createStatement();} and I have Import what is needed but there is an "illegal Start of type" This is my first time that I code, sorry if I asked a bad question

Comment: Does your server support XMLA? - Else you may have to use another JDBC driver.

Comment: As I have searched, yes it does support XMLA